# Global extrema of $f(x,y,z) = x^2-y^2+z$ on $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}$ on $\frac{x^2}{2}+y^2\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

(See edits below about what I did wrong)

I'm asked to find the global extrema of two functions each in a different region. I think my results are correct, but I have no solutions, so I don't know if I forgot something or made a mistake somewhere and I would like your confirmation, thank you.

---

a) 
$f(x,y,z) = x^2-y^2+z$ on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$. 
So inside of the domain, we have $(2x,-2y,1)=(0,0,0)$ which is never true. On the border, we use Lagrange and get $(2x,-2y,1)=\lambda(2x,2y,2z)$. So $\lambda=\frac{1}{2z}, y=0, 2x=\frac{x}{z}$ so $z=\frac{1}{2}$ if $x\neq 0$. To get $x$, we plug that into our constraint and get $x=\pm \frac{3}{4}$. If $x=0$, then $z=\pm 1$ using again our constraint.

So there is a global minimum of $-1$ at $(0,0,-1)$ and a global maximum of $\frac{9}{16}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{17}{16}$ at $(\pm \frac{3}{4},0,\frac{1}{2})$

---

b)
 
$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}$ on the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{2}+y^2\leq 1$

On the inside, we have $(x,y)=(0,0)$ So $x=0=y$. On the border, we plug $\frac{x^2}{2}=1-y^2$ into our function. So we get $1-\frac{y^2}{2}$, $-1\leq y\leq 1$. So $f'=-y=0$. So $y=0$ and $x=\pm \sqrt{2}$. For the endpoints, we have $y=\pm 1, x=0$. So the candidates are $(0,0), (\pm \sqrt{2},0), (0,\pm 1)$. So we have a global maximum of $1$ at $(\pm \sqrt{2},0)$ and a global minimum of $0$ at $(0,0)$.

---

Thanks for your feedback !

---

Edit : part b) seems correct. In part a), for $x\neq 0, z=\frac{1}{2},y=0$, when I plug into the constraint to find $x$, I should get $x^2=\frac{3}{4}$ so $x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. I forgot to take the square root for $x$ (in fact, I put the $\pm$ in front of $\frac{3}{4}$ without taking the square root of $\frac{3}{4}$, which is obviously not correct).

Also, I have somewhat overseen the equation $-2y=\frac{y}{z}$ and only focused on $2x=\frac{x}{z}$. 

$y$ is not necessarily $0$. If $z=-\frac{1}{2}$, then $x=0$ but $y\neq 0$. Here, we have the same case as above, i.e. we plug $y$ into our constraint with $x=0, z=-\frac{1}{2}$ and get $y=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

So finally, we have a global maximum of $\frac{5}{4}$ at $(\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0,\frac{1}{2})$ and a global minimum of $- \frac{5}{4}$ at $(0,\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first exercise with $f = x^2-y^2+z$ after forming the lagrangian as

$$
L(x,y,z,\lambda,\epsilon) = f + \lambda (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 - \epsilon^2)
$$
 Here $\epsilon$ is a slack variable introduced in order to transform the inequality into an equality, the stationary conditions are
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 2 \lambda  x+2 x& = & 0 \\
 2 \lambda  y-2 y& = & 0 \\
 2 \lambda  z+1& = & 0 \\
 x^2+y^2+z^2-1-\epsilon^2& =& 0 \\
 -2 \epsilon  \lambda&  =& 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

or

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 (\lambda+1)x& = & 0 \\
 (\lambda-1)y& = & 0 \\
 2 \lambda  z+1& = & 0 \\
 x^2+y^2+z^2-1-\epsilon^2& =& 0 \\
 -2 \epsilon  \lambda&  =& 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and after solving
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
x & y & z & \lambda & \epsilon & f \\
 0 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & -\frac{5}{4} \\
 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & -\frac{5}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -1 \\
 -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & 0 & \frac{5}{4} \\
 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & 0 & \frac{5}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Note that in all solutions $\epsilon = 0$ revealing that all such solutions are located at the boundary.

Comment: @Poujh Thanks for showme the typo. Now it is corrected.

Comment: But in this case, what did I do wrong in a) ? Is my Lagrange set up false ?

Comment: I can't find my mistake in a). I mean, I just set up $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$ as usual and solved, being wary of the cases where one or several variables are $0$

Comment: Ah, found it ! When $x\neq 0$ and $z=\frac{1}{2}, y=0$, if I plug into the constraint, I get $x^2+\frac{1}{4}=1$, so $x^2=\frac{3}{4}$ so $x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. I forgot to take the square root for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for a) On the border you can use $$y^2=1-x^2-z^2$$ and you will get
$$f(x,\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2},z)=2x^2+z^2+z-1$$ only two variables.
Your second problem is ok.

Comment: But how do I optimize that for a) ? I mean, I still have two variables so I cannot just take the derivative and set it equal to 0.

Comment: Why not? This must be done.

Comment: See here https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/min_max/min_max.html

Comment: So I take the gradient and set it equal to zero and then solve ? Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes this is correct, see additionally the link above.

Comment: Well, I don't get the same results for a) than I got with Lagrange. Here, I get $x=0, z= -\frac{1}{2}$ so $y=\pm \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Do you see any mistake in part a) ? Because I don't see where I went wrong using Lagrange. I'm a bit troubled.